# What is the best option for a Tableau using custom SQL code that needs to be translated?

Tags: sql-server, tableau-desktop

We are using Tableau 2022.
We have this Portuguese Dashboard that has DB source as custom SQL.
We now need to translate that Dashboard into Italian.
So We now need to have SQL code to use the Italian field names (that contains the Italian data) for this newly created italian version.

**QUESTION** :
Is it a better practices to have another query with all the new italian column names in it's sql code for this new Italian dashboard or we should instead APPEND the newly created sql code referring to these new italian columns all in the same query that already has the portuguese column names ?
Or is there a better way to do this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you store each language variant as a view in your database? Its always easier to work with clean data in tableau.

Comment: Thank you. You then mean to have views for each language even thought it will be exacly the same logic but with different column names rigth ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the both data sources have same fields and  dashboard is complex and you want to avoid redo/validation efforts on calculated fields, filters etc
.

I'd edit the custom sql so that it would return exactly same field names for to tableau to use.

In custom sql

Old: SELECT portugese_field_name....

New: SELECT italian_field_name AS portugese_field_name...

Then on tableau user interface i would rename only the visible fields to italian.

Comment: Hi and thank you for the reply. I think this is a good idea as for it would mean that once in Desktop interface i will NOT need to dragg and drop those new italian fields to replace the portuguese ones rght ? Simply need to rename the Portuguese as you indicated.

Comment: QUESTION : Did i understood correctly by saying rhat i will not need to dragg and dropp any new field over the original ones by using this method ?

Comment: Yes you did understand correctly.

Comment: Oh nice! Thank you all in this forum. Will try it and see how it goes.